# C++11 - Wrong constructor called in GCC/Clang (not in VS 2013)

Tags: gcc, c++11, constructor, clang

I have this code which works fine in VS 2013 but doesn't compile in either GCC 4.8 or clang 3.3!

```
    AND_end(c)->next = new ListNode<Point>{ b->val };
```

The error message is the following: "cannot convert from "Point" to "int".

Now, gradually, member val of b is a Point:

```
struct Point
{
int x;
int y;

double distance(const Point& other) const
{
    if (this == &other)
        return 0.;

    return std::sqrt(std::pow(other.y - y, 2.) + std::pow(other.x - x, 2.));
}

bool operator==(const Point& other)
{
    return x == other.x && y == other.y;
}

bool operator!=(const Point& other)
{
    return !(*this == other);
}
};
```

b is a Line:

```
using Line = ListNode<Point>*;
```

a ListNode is a typical node for a singly linked list:

```
template<typename T>
struct ListNode
{
T val;              // Value
ListNode* next = nullptr;   // Next node in the list

// Constructor: takes a value of type T and optionally a pointer to the next node
explicit ListNode(T v, ListNode* n = nullptr)
    : val{ v }, next{ n }
{
    // Empty body, both member variables are initialized already
}
};
```

So, the line of code that doesn't compile should do the following: create a new ListNode, with T = Point, by supplying to the explicit ListNode constructor its first (and only) argument T v, which is a Point (b->val is a Point). This argument will be copied into the ListNode member val by copy, using the default copy constructor.
What seems to happen in both GCC and clang is that b->val is supplied to the Point constructor, hence the error message above (and for the sake of completeness, and additional warning is given: "missing field 'y' initializer").
VC++12 seems to get it all right instead.

So, what's up? Am I missing anything obvious (maybe, happens from time to time) or is there a nasty problem here?

Comment: We can't see `Line`'s definition, nor what the object `b` actually _is_.  Can you reduce this to a http://sscce.org/?

Comment: Using `pow` to square numbers... really?  Use multiplication for that.

Comment: FYI, here's a reproducer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa69778b599c8a1 -- you can fix it by doing member initialization with () instead of {}

Comment: Uhm, I can see it: Line is a typedef for ListNode<Point>*.
Anyway I can post a shortened example, 100 lines. Better use pastebin or 100 lines is still acceptable to copy paste in here?

Comment: @Nate Kohl yeah that's it! So is that a bug in both GCC and Clang, which give the same error message?? Weird to say the least o_O

Comment: The reason why this fails is that list-initialization for an aggregate favours aggregate-initialization over copy-construction. This still seems to be the case in the latest C++1y draft.

Comment: @DyP yeah in fact that dream of "uniform initialization with curly braces" is destined to remain just a dream, in fact you can't even use that style in class member defaulting...what a mess :D

So, the reason it works fine in VS 2013 is yet again that Microsoft isn't on par with the standardization of its compiler yet...and I thought that for once the competition had bugs...!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you do not have copy constructor for Point, therefore, in this line,

explicit ListNode(T v, ListNode* n = nullptr)
    : val{ v }, next{ n }

since there's no copy constructor, val{v} will try to initialize by aggregate.

From 8.5.1,

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors.
>
> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list,
>   as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken
>   as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing
>   subscript or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause.

For a point type, the aggregate initialization shall be val {v.x, v.y}.

Or, you can implement a copy constructor for Point class.

GCC & Clang are correct. VS is wrong and it should reject your code.

Comment: The default and copy constructor are always synthesized by the compiler...unless deleted, so I don't think this is the point and I can't solve the problem by manually adding a Copy constructor. I'll try though...